# trying to create a simple Solr master/slave configuration getting indexFetcher error on SLAVE trying to connect to master

Tags: solr, solr-search

2021-07-26 17:13:30.420 INFO  (qtp210506412-18) [   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/info/logging params={wt=json&*=1627318946019&since=0} status=0 QTime=0
2021-07-26 17:13:40.423 INFO  (qtp210506412-22) [   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/info/logging params={wt=json&*=1627318946019&since=0} status=0 QTime=0
2021-07-26 17:13:46.305 WARN  (indexFetcher-90-thread-1) [   ] o.a.s.h.IndexFetcher Master at: https://localhost:8986/solr/#/master is not available. Index fetch failed by exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8986/solr/#/master: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html.

Comment: `https://localhost:8986/solr/#/master` this is an invalid URL for replication - the part after `#` as an anchor and is only relevant on the client side in HTML / Javascript. You probably want the actual replication path. Usually something like `http://host:port/<core>/replication`.

Comment: That was it, thanks so much for the comment and noticing that.

Answer (score 0):

The given URL is invalid for replication (`https://localhost:8986/solr/#/master`) - the part after # as an anchor and is only relevant on the client side in HTML / Javascript.

You probably want the actual replication path. This is usually something like:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<core>/replication
```

Change the current configuration and reload the core / restart Solr and replication should start properly.